# Get audio frequencies and amplitudes as float array

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, frequency, frequency-analysis

We need to analyze an audio file so that we'll get it's properties like frequencies and amplitudes as float array ( not as curve or waveform ).

Is there any library in programming langues, for example any function which gets sound file and sample rate as input and returns an array of floats representing its frequencies and amplitudes based on sample rate.

Or any even software giving us such results.

Comment: Quick comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html. I'll look into it further and maybe I'll find something good to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very easy! use GetSpectrumData and GetOutputData in unity on audioSource component and based on the current time of AS it will give you float array